# Check if an email already exists in firestore auth on signup (Angular)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As a user signs up to our app, I want them to know whether the email they are trying to sign up with already exists, without having to submit the form (A.K.A on blur of the email field). As it stands, the user has to enter their details and click signup before it let's them know whether the email is taken or not.

The required behaviour can be observed with spotify signup where you enter the email, and as soon as you click away you see the following:

[image]

So far, I have written a cloud function (http) that is triggered on blur that calls the `getUserByEmail` function from firestore admin auth. The function is as follows:

```
export const checkUserEmail = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    corsHandler(req, res, async () => {
        try {
            const email = req.body.email;
            await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email);

            res.send({status: 200});
            return;
        } catch(e) {
            return Helpers._handleError(res, 400, e.message);
        }
    })
});
```

This does work as I can now check at this moment whether or not an email exists, however the problem is it takes anywhere between 3-10 seconds to validate (long enough for the user to get deeper into the signup process).

Is there a way to either:

1. Speed up the cloud function or
2. Validate whether a user has already authenticated with the email provided directly on the client side with firestore?

Thanks in advance

Comment: An asynchronous validator should be pretty quick and you wouldn't need a cloud function. However, letting the user know that an email is taken could be considered a security risk. You're letting the attacker know that the email is valid, unlike sending a generic error message.

Comment: Maybe you can consider this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#fetch-sign-inmethods-for-email ?

Comment: @AJT82 that was a fantastic solution! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `users` collection, which you may be doing already. This can store user information and often proves to be really handle since the auth user can't be updated with fields it doesn't how out of the box.

You can store users' emails here and check the collection for the user's input compared to the email field of the `users` collection here.

Comment: Yeah so we do have a users collection that like you say stores the email amongst other information - The problem is that I wanted to check if the user exists in the firestore authentication tab for extra security

Comment: I think if you're doing it how you're doing it now in an onRequest cloud function, and only returning `true` or `false`, there's not much different in terms of security. Either way you know if your database contains accounts associated with emails.